# Strip wav header in c#

Tags: c#, header, wav, strip

I want to be able to strip off a header from a wav file.

Is there any way to do this in C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WAV Files uses the standard RIFF header format. See [example here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/riffparser.aspx).

You can use [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/Concatenation_Wave_Files.aspx) as a starting point. It contains methods for reading and writing Wav files. Should be a simple job to strip/clear out the header info.

Comment: Watch out. That wav header parser on the Code Project link assumes it is always 44 bytes long, which is NOT always the case, especially these days.